# Selenium giving error: "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator"

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I attempted to retrieve an tag using its classname from a webpage using Selenium.

I wrote the following:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

def launchBrowser():
    os.environ['PATH'] += r"/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver_mac_arm64"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_id-driver-method-selenium-python/")
    element = driver.find_element("class_name", "header-main_wrapper")
    #element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=bp3-button bp3-minimal]")
    #link = element.get_attribute("href")
    #link.click()
    while(True):
        pass

launchBrowser()
```

After debugging `element = driver.find_element("class_name", "header-main_wrapper")` returns the error above. I'm unsure why. I think I followed the method signature properly which is why I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I believe you need single-quotes around the class value.  `@class='bp3-button bp3-minimal'`

Answer (score 1):

Change the below line:

```
element = driver.find_element("class_name", "header-main_wrapper")
```

To:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "header-main_wrapper")
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```